# Javascript OLE Word

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ole

I want to show a MS Word environment in an Iframe without all the toobars. The document that is being showed contains input fields. After these fields are filled in, the document must be printed. I have created the print button and want the (filled in) document printed when this button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286023/en-us/) may be the answer to your question.

Comment: Can you tell how this ActiveX component can help? I don't see how to disable the menubar, toolbar and ribbon.

Comment: Try this within your vbscript call.

Dim oBar As CommandBar
 
For Each oBar In Application.CommandBars
    If oBar.Visible Then oBar.Visible = False
Next oBar